# PhoneGap in Salesforce Mobile(hybrid) ios template

Tags: xcode, cordova, salesforce

When creating an hybrid iOS App I see that they are using PhoneGap. Is PhoneGap not generating native code for multiple platforms - if so, then I dont understand what "phonegap-1.2.0" is doing in hybrid iOS projects?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The PhoneGap plugin for iso is a way of calling native code from javascript:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins

Comment: Thanks, I am working on installing this, but it gives me a lot of errors installing it. I will accept your answer as soon I get it running. I have posted the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230864/error-installing-weinre-on-mac